# replacing SRC withing javascript using variables and getElementById and getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't understand why this doesn't work
It tried to open within folders rather then an SRC website

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com" width="300"></iframe>
<p id="URL">Tik hier een url:<input type="text"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('URL').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            var website = document.getElementById('URL');
            var urlOutput = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
            urlOutput.src = website.value;

        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from `"website.value"`?

Comment: thanks for the response, at least it tries to do something now... Only is it trying to open files within the source map rather then opening a new website within the iframe p.s i've added the edit within the help question I hope that is common practice here and i'm not being an idiot here =D new to stack overflow

Comment: Try moving `id="URL"` from the `p` to the `input`?

Answer (score 3):

`.value` can be used for `input`, `textarea` elements. The element with id `URL` is an paragraph.

Instead, get the input element i:e `document.querySelector('input');`.

```js
document.getElementById('URL').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    var website = document.querySelector('input');
    var urlOutput = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    urlOutput.src = website.value;
  }
});
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com" width="300"></iframe>
<p id="URL">Tik hier een url:<input type="text"></p>
```

Comment: thanks for the response, however I tried to apply this code to it but it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm probably doing something wrong still

Comment: it seems to still try to find an undefined location within my computer itself rather then opening a website within the iframe

Comment: @Weedse — then you're not typing a proper URL into the input

Answer (score 0):

Just assign id to input tag.

change this

```
<p id="URL">Tik hier een url:<input  type="text"></p>
```

to

```
<p>Tik hier een url:<input id="URL" type="text"></p>
```

```js
document.getElementById('URL').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    var website = document.getElementById('URL');
    var urlOutput = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    urlOutput.src = website.value;

  }
});
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com" width="300"></iframe>
<p>Tik hier een url:<input id="URL" type="text"></p>
```